# What could cause this crash on the libdispatch-manager thread?

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, crash-reports

```
Date/Time: 2013-05-22 21:31:31.863 -0400  
OS Version: iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)  
Report Version: 104  

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000  
Crashed Thread: 1  

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
Thread 0:  
0 CoreFoundation 0x3203f950 -[NSArrayM dealloc] + 128    
1 Foundation 0x32999218 -[NSFunctionExpression dealloc] + 56  
2 Foundation 0x329991d8 -[NSKeyPathExpression dealloc] + 36  
3 Foundation 0x3299914c -[NSComparisonPredicate dealloc] + 40  
4 CoreData 0x31f6b672 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 1362  
5 CoreFoundation 0x32045034 _CFXNotificationPost + 1424  
6 Foundation 0x3295b594 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68  
7 CoreData 0x31ef9712 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 74  
8 CoreData 0x31ef8c72 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 294  9 CoreData 0x31e7abf4 - [NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2676  
10 CoreData 0x31e7a10a _performRunLoopAction + 266  
11 CoreFoundation 0x320c96ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION + 18  
12 CoreFoundation 0x320c79bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272  
13 CoreFoundation 0x320c7d12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738  
14 CoreFoundation 0x3203aeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352  
15 CoreFoundation 0x3203ad44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100    
16 GraphicsServices 0x35bef2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70  
17 UIKit 0x33f502fc UIApplicationMain + 1116  
18 MyApp 0x00003fd6 main (main.m:16)  
19 MyApp 0x00003f8c 0x1000 + 12172  

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager  
Thread 1 Crashed:  
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3a486648 kevent64 + 24  
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x3a3b6974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792  
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x3a3b6654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That crash almost certainly did not actually occur on the dispatch manager thread (despite what the crashreport claims) since it is blocked in the kernel in the `kevent64` syscall.

CrashReporter may have misidentified the crashing thread, or your process could have been sent a `SEGV` signal externally.

If there are other threads beside the ones you list here, it's worth looking through them to see if the could be the crashing ones, otherwise the culprit is the `dealloc` on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with the predicate that you're using in an `NSFetchedResultsController`. The problem occurred while handling a notification, possibly one posted when saving changes to a managed object context. That's about all that the stack trace says. **What** is wrong with the predicate and why it's a problem at this time are impossible to answer without seeing some code.